# Combining dataframe rows based on a value in a range

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to bring together (it's not really a merge or join) data contained in two dataframes based on whether a value in one falls within a range on the second.

data is at the end of the post for convenience.
One data frame (df1) looks like this:

```
      Chromosome Position  P.value start.range end.range name
               2  4553493 8.23e-05     4453493   4653493    A
               3 24548810 1.04e-04    24448810  24648810    B
               1  9952003 2.09e-04     9852003  10052003    C
```

The second df is much longer, but head(df2) looks like this:

```
          ensembl_gene_id chromosome_name start_position end_position
          OS01G0281600               1       10048273     10050309
          OS01G0281400               1       10021423     10027120
          OS01G0281301               1       10019633     10020376
          OS01G0281200               1       10011875     10015468
          OS01G0281100               1       10008075     10011595
          OS01G0281000               1       10003952     10007742
```

I need to match the rows from each IF df1$Position is within 100,000 of either df2$start_position or df2$end_position (ie `((df1$Position - df2$start_position)<100000 | (df1$Position - df2$end_position)<100000)`.

I need, as output, a list or dataframe of the rows that match.  There will be multiple df2 values that match df1, and there are multiple entries per chromosome, though df1$name is unique.  I've been trying various applications of ddply and custom functions, but am coming up short.  Any ideas?

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Chromosome = c(2L, 3L, 1L), Position = c(4553493L, 
24548810L, 9952003L), P.value = c(8.23e-05, 0.000104, 0.000209
), start.range = c(4453493, 24448810, 9852003), end.range = c(4653493, 
24648810, 10052003), name = c("A", "B", "C")), .Names = c("Chromosome", 
"Position", "P.value", "start.range", "end.range", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
3L))

df2 <- structure(list(ensembl_gene_id = c("OS01G0281600", "OS01G0281400", 
"OS01G0281301", "OS01G0281200", "OS01G0281100", "OS01G0281000", 
"OS01G0280500", "OS01G0280400", "OS01G0280000", "OS01G0279900", 
"OS01G0279800", "OS01G0279700", "OS01G0279400", "OS01G0279300", 
"OS01G0279200", "OS01G0279100", "OS01G0279000", "OS01G0278900", 
"OS01G0278950", "OS02G0183000", "OS02G0182850", "OS02G0182900", 
"OS02G0182700", "OS02G0182800", "OS02G0182500", "OS02G0182300", 
"OS02G0181900", "OS02G0182100", "OS02G0181800", "OS02G0181400", 
"OS02G0180900", "OS02G0180700", "OS02G0180500", "OS02G0180200", 
"OS02G0180400", "OS02G0180100", "OS03G0640300", "OS03G0640400", 
"OS03G0640000", "OS03G0640100", "OS03G0639700", "OS03G0639800", 
"OS03G0639600", "OS03G0639400", "OS03G0639300", "OS03G0638900", 
"OS03G0639100", "OS03G0638400", "OS03G0638800", "OS03G0638300", 
"OS03G0638200"), chromosome_name = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), start_position = c(10048273L, 
10021423L, 10019633L, 10011875L, 10008075L, 10003952L, 9967185L, 
9962807L, 9936850L, 9928971L, 9917593L, 9913390L, 9889550L, 9887657L, 
9878384L, 9874379L, 9866730L, 9859354L, 9863216L, 4639932L, 4629617L, 
4630446L, 4616832L, 4625425L, 4598883L, 4594375L, 4567630L, 4573831L, 
4563073L, 4551426L, 4521670L, 4497115L, 4486531L, 4460342L, 4481872L, 
4455016L, 24630180L, 24638186L, 24616417L, 24621460L, 24591421L, 
24596843L, 24574540L, 24564913L, 24544511L, 24487877L, 24514494L, 
24466606L, 24476060L, 24454477L, 24449135L), end_position = c(10050309L, 
10027120L, 10020376L, 10015468L, 10011595L, 10007742L, 9969073L, 
9966715L, 9947933L, 9935981L, 9921565L, 9917318L, 9902737L, 9889123L, 
9885517L, 9876678L, 9870864L, 9860677L, 9866617L, 4641686L, 4630180L, 
4634616L, 4621974L, 4628750L, 4601382L, 4595386L, 4573049L, 4578257L, 
4566597L, 4552860L, 4523668L, 4500124L, 4489409L, 4463571L, 4483470L, 
4457715L, 24634746L, 24641449L, 24617859L, 24629502L, 24596437L, 
24600376L, 24579212L, 24565726L, 24549550L, 24489307L, 24515219L, 
24473558L, 24480927L, 24457481L, 24453890L)), .Names = c("ensembl_gene_id", 
"chromosome_name", "start_position", "end_position"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-51L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
ddply(df1, .(name), function(x) {
 df2[(x$Position - df2$start_position) < 100000 | 
     (x$Position - df2$end_position) < 100000, ]
})
```

Comment: This was really helpful, and got me almost the whole way there when I ran it over a bigger set. I was getting some cross matching (between chromosomes) at that point, so just added in one more line to end up with this:  
    ddply(df1, .(name), function(x) {  
    df2[(x$Position - df2$start_position) < 100000 |  
    (x$Position - df2$end_position) < 100000, ]  
    })